# Fortran makefile circular dependency dropped

Tags: makefile, fortran, circular-dependency, intel-fortran

So I am trying to run a Fortran code from someone else with the Intel Fortran compiler on a mac. But when I try to run the corresponding makefile, I get the error messages "make[1]: Circular release.makefile out <- release.makefile dependency dropped." and so on.

I have little knowledge of Fortran, so I would appreciate any help. I already tested to run some simple helloworld.f90 files and makefiles, to rule out that it is a compiler problem, and those work. However, the code I am trying to run is downloaded from a reputable scientific journal, so I assume the code (makefiles and Fortran files) should be correct too, leaving me at loss. This is my first stackoverflow post, so if I forgot something please let me know.

The makefile is:

```
release:
    # ENV = /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh intel64
    make -f release.makefile

debug:
    # ENV = /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh intel64
    make -f debug.makefile
    dsymutil $(OUT).out

hpcrelease:
    make -f hpcrelease.makefile

pbs:
    make -f pbs.makefile

compilesubmit:
    make -f hpcrelease.makefile
    make -f pbs.makefile
    qsub $(OUT).pbs

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.mod *.MOD *genmod* *~ 
    rm -fr *.dSYM
```

and the file release.makefile writes:

```
FC = ifort
FCFLAGS = -m64 -traceback -O3 -qopenmp -implicitnone  -Wl,-stack_size,0x100000000 -L/Users/josie/Desktop/Uni/Economics/Moll/SuiteSparse-master/lib -lumfpack -lamd -lcholmod -lcolamd -lsuitesparseconfig -lblas 
LDFLAFS = -m64 -traceback -O3 -qopenmp -implicitnone  -Wl,-stack_size,0x100000000 -L/Users/josie/Desktop/Uni/Economics/Moll/SuiteSparse-master/lib -lumfpack -lamd -lcholmod -lcolamd -lsuitesparseconfig -lblas 
# -O3

PROG = $(OUT)

MOD = Parameters.o Globals.o umfpack.o Procedures.o 

SUBR =  AllocateArrays.o SetParameters.o Grids.o IterateBellman.o HJBUpdate.o cumnor.o rtsec.o StationaryDistribution.o SaveSteadyStateOutput.o DistributionStatistics.o rtbis.o rtflsp.o InitialSteadyState.o FinalSteadyState.o SolveSteadyStateEqum.o Calibration.o MomentConditions.o dfovec.o newuoa-h.o newuob-h.o update.o trsapp-h.o biglag.o bigden.o mnbrak.o golden.o sort2.o  CumulativeConsumption.o  FnDiscountRate.o  OptimalConsumption.o FnHoursBC.o  ImpulseResponses.o IRFSequence.o Transition.o  SaveIRFOutput.o IterateTransitionStickyRb.o IterateTransOneAssetStickyRb.o FnCapitalEquity.o CumulativeConsTransition.o DiscountedMPC.o DiscountedMPCTransition.o


OBJ = $(MOD) $(SUBR)

$(PROG).out: $(OBJ) Main.o
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
Main.o: $(MOD)

%: %.o
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $<
```

the error I get is

```
Fortran % make -f makefile
# ENV = /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh intel64
make -f release.makefile
make[1]: Circular release.makefile.out <- release.makefile dependency dropped.
make[1]: Circular Main.f90.out <- Main.f90 dependency dropped.
make[1]: Circular Parameters.f90.out <- Parameters.f90 dependency dropped.
make[1]: Circular Globals.f90.out <- Globals.f90 dependency dropped.
make[1]: Circular umfpack.f90.out <- umfpack.f90 dependency dropped.
make[1]: Circular Procedures.f90.out <- Procedures.f90 dependency dropped.
make[1]: `Main.o' is up to date.
```

Since the error already occurs with the release.makefile, I refer from giving the other files since I believe the error is the same for all scripts? Correct me if I am wrong and those are necessary.

Comment: Well, one problem for sure is you've used the variable `OUT`, here: `PROG = $(OUT)` but you've never defined it.  This means that `PROG` is empty and the rule for `$(PROG).out: ...` defines just `.out`.  Depending on the version of GNU make you're using, this might assume you want to create a suffix rule.

Comment: Just a tip, not related to your problem: you should _never_ use raw `make` in your makefiles.  **Always** use the variable `$(MAKE)` when you want to invoke sub-makes.

Comment: Does the code actually compile and work as you expect? What makes you think there is a problem?